# Chrome annoyingly opens a corresponding line in main.bundle.ts every time I add a breakpoint in a .ts file

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, angular-cli

I'm developing an Angular (v4.3.5) SPA, serving it with Angular CLI's `ng serve` command and debugging it through Chrome Developer Tools. Last week something strange started to happen and I can't seem to do anything to change it to the way it was before: in Chrome Dev Tools, when I click on the line number to add a breakpoint in my `.ts` files, Chrome Dev Tools also open the corresponding line in `main.bundle.ts`, so now every single time I add a breakpoint I have to close `main.bundle.ts` or click back on the title of `.ts` file. It's very annoying. Is there a new change in default settings or something? Because I couldn't find anything related to that (although I'm not even sure how to google this issue...)

So my question is: what can I do to force Chrome not to open `main.bundle.ts` every time I add a breakpoint?

EDIT: I just found out this issue happens only when I run `ng serve` from Visual Studio Code terminal.

Comment: sounds like an issue, could you please file one on crbug.com with component Platform > DevTools?

Comment: After trying to write down steps to recreate I figured out this issue appears only when I run `ng serve` from Visual Studio Code terminal, I will dig deeper into this and write here what I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a Chrome bug - updating it to Version `61.0.3163.79` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (chromeDevTools):

Map `webpack://./` to `/` in your project workspace

[image]

Comment: This helped me, but not 100%: if I stop serving from VS Code and start `ng serve` from VS Code again, I need to close DevTools window and reopen it again, otherwise the bug persists. It's way less annoying though, thanks :)

Comment: The bug also persists not only if I start `ng serve` again, but if I change the source code and save it - then webpack recompiles the source, reloads the webpage and here we go again... So your answer didn't really helped that much, sorry.

Comment: Remember that you need to refresh with the page loaded AND devtools open. This is due to a limitation of chrome: It can't fetch js and map files for that js in the same request.

Comment: But why does this bug appear ONLY when I serve from VS Code? If I run `ng serve` from command line, everything is ok. Also, why didn't I experience this bug before?

Comment: Chrome updated how sourcemaps worked. It depends on what kind of sourcemap VS is expecting: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145#issuecomment-294361203 Thats a huge thread about sourcemaps in chrome (angular-cli uses webpack under the hood)

Comment: Looks like it was a Chrome bug, I updated it today to v61 and the breakpoints now work normally, just like before the bug (and no need for custom Workspace Mappings).